# How find if a point is in a wedge of a other point javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a canvas and I draw 2 points.
I have to draw 2 straight lines from each point. Then we must check whether the point *u* sees the point *v* and vice versa.

To know, it is necessary to see if the point *v* is in the **wedge** of the point *u* and vice versa:

-[Here *V* is the wedge of *U*, so *V* sees *U* but *U* don't see *V*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0b9w.png)

-[Here *V* sees *U* and *U* sees *V*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNVqS.png)

If the 2 points are in the wedge of each one then a segment is drawn between the 2 points.

How can I do that kind of wedge in a canvas javascript?

Comment: Is this with infinite distance?

Comment: @LiamMacDonald Infinite distance for points or lines ? If it's lines yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Cross product of two vectors.

Using the cross product of a line (x1,y1, x2,y2) ax a vector (x2-x1, y2-y1) and a vector from the line start  to a point x,y  (x - x1, y - y1) will give you a number that is negative if the point is to the left of the line, zero if the point is along the line, and positive if the point is to the right of the line.

Thus for a point to be in the view of the V it has to be to the right of the V's left arm AND to the left of the V's right arm.

A V is described as follows

```
const v = {
    lx : ?,  // point on left V
    ly : ?, 
    x : ?,  // point of V
    y : ?,
    rx : ?,
    ry : ?,
}
```

The the following function will return true if `V1` can see `V2` where `v1` and `v2` are objects as described above.

```
function canSee(v1,v2){
    const lx = v1.lx - v1.x;  // get vector from center to left line end
    const ly = v1.ly - v1.y;
    const cx = v2.x  - v1.x;  // get vector from center to v2's center
    const cy = v2.y  - v1.y;
    const rx = v1.rx - v1.x;  // get vector from center to right line end
    const ry = v1.ry - v1.y;

    // get the cross product of left and right arms to the other V's center
    const lc = lx * cy - ly * cx;
    const rc = rx * cy - ry * cx;
    
    return (lc > 0 && rc < 0);  // return true if V2 center is right of
                                // left arm and left of arm.
                                // else return false;
}
```

Using the function you can find out if both can see each other as follows.

```
if(canSee(v1, v2) && canSee(v2, v1)){ } // both can see each other
else { } //one or none can see the other
```

It is important that the points are on the correct sides. Left and right is defined when standing at a line start and looking towards the line end

Comment: It's working ! Thx @Blindman67 
Can you see this one please : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45692688/algorithm-noobtuse-in-javascript